# Why doesn't mvc4 webpages_Membership use a Salt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write as secure as possible system using the MVC4 framework. I have noticed that tables are automatically created in my database to handle the Web Pages security in MVC4. I have stated that the framework will use a salt in its authentication but on creating a user this is not the case.

The field is there in the database but it is `NULL`.

How do I apply this feature?

Thanks